# Jenkins - No such file or directory Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: jenkins

I am trying to run a shell  script via Jenkins. Its a simple shell script that will run a command called autopkg run -v Firefox.munki

When I run this in the prompt from CLI it works fine. When I add the same script to Jenkins I get an error

Script Location : /Users/mstark/Desktop/scripts/t2.sh

Error:

```
Started by user Michael Stark 
Running as SYSTEM
Building in workspace /Users/mstark/.jenkins/workspace/autopkg
[autopkg] $ /bin/sh -xe /var/folders/ln/814pyyl53jgb9lszytdwxl3w0000gn/T/jenkins11923866224901317891.sh
+ /Users/mstark/Desktop/tscript/ts2.sh
/var/folders/ln/814pyyl53jgb9lszytdwxl3w0000gn/T/jenkins11923866224901317891.sh: line 2: /Users/mstark/Desktop/tscript/ts2.sh: No such file or directory
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Strange but the shell script works fine via CLI.

Comment: The Jenkins machine that your build runs on I assume is not the same machine that you tested the script with using your local command line. Is the `ts2.sh` script located at `/Users/mstark/Desktop/tscript/ts2.sh` on the Jenkins machine? That path looks like a local path, since it includes what I assume is your username on your local machine.

Comment: it finally worked I had to give the complete path in the script itself. e.g. /user/local/munki/ autopkg run -v chrome.munki